# Listen dbus-monitor messages in Python 2.4

Tags: python, linux, dbus, python-2.4

I'm working on an old Linux with only Python 2.4.

When I launch the following command `dbus-monitor --system` and when I press a pushbutton, a daemon triggers this message:

> signal sender=:1.1 -> dest=(null destination) serial=10 path=/com/mindscape/karotz/Button; interface=com.mindscape.karotz.KarotzInterface; member=click

I would catch these messages in my script, do you have any idea?

Comment: Do you have any python binding in place to use? E.g. some old version of dbus-python which is compatible with Python 2.4 and the libdbus version you have? Or is that perhaps part of the question and something you need help with?

Comment: Well, actually I can import "dbus" but not "gobject". I tried to follow this tutorial designed for Python 2.4+ https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-python/doc/tutorial.html#setting-up-an-event-loop

Someone told me I need a gobject binding, but no idea how to get it. I found /usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so on my system.

Comment: What if you install this package: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyGObject/2.10.1

Comment: Er, I'm not on an i686 CPU but on ARMv4 (ARM9), is there another link I've not found?

Comment: I'd actually suggest you start with another question on SO about how to get the dependencies you need sorted. Or perhaps even a question about how to do this using some other tools than e.g. dbus-python for the D-Bus work.